# Mongodb timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I have stored date in unix timestamp format in mongodb >> 1449060622
now I want to add milliseconds as well so if records inserted in same seconds can be sorted properly.

can someone suggest me that using js new Date() is more better or simply (new Date).getTime() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you store times in MongoDB you should really consider using the native Date type instead. Not only does it provide you with millisecond precision, it also unlocks a lot of features which are unavailable for simple integer, like [date aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) for example.

If you really don't want to use native dates for some obscure reason (I couldn't think of a good one) or don't want to convert your whole database (really, you should) and need a higher precision, you might consider to add new values as floating point values. This ensures interoperability with the old data because integers and floating point values usually can be converted and compared between each other easily.